# What is parentValueWatch in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, performance

I am using batarang to determine the source of some performance issues. One of the bigger culprits was my own code, but this parentValueWatch thing is now topping the charts and I have no idea where it is or what triggers it. My brains are on the floor from so much Googling... anybody know?

*(AngularJS v1.2.24)*

[image]

Comment: This is a function that watches for changes in parent scope vs. isolated scope of a directive that uses `scope: {param: "="}`. Here's the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.24/src/ng/compile.js#L1487). Make sure that your bound values are not bound to long-running functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ParentValueWatch` is when a directive checks in its parent scope to see if any values have changed and, therefore, need to be changed itself.

Consider the simple directive,

```
{
   restrict:"AE",
   scope:{
      foo:'='
   }
}
```

Now let's say in the parent scope, `foo` is an object.

```
$parent.$scope.foo = {
    bar:"zim"
}
```

Each `$digest` cycle, the child $scope will need to check the parent scope's `foo` value and each of its properties.

If `foo` was a really big and deeply nested object, this would take a long time, thus why it is taking so long.

Inside the HTML, this might look like this:

```
<div parent-directive>
<div foo-directive foo=bar></div></div>
```

One quick work around for this is to "freeze-dry" the values by using ng-init.

```
<div parent-directive>
<div foo-directive ng-init='zug={bar:$parent.foo.bar}' foo=zug></div></div>
```

Now the value that is bound to a new object. You lose easy binding, but gain performance.

It is always a tradeoff.